# Eclipse tomcat-7 server skip all breakpoints

Tags: eclipse, debugging, tomcat7, mode

I am trying to debug my code and the tomcat server starts in debug mode, but the eclipse doesn't show debug perpective and however it skips all breakpoints and is working like in normal run.

So can someone tell me how to fix this, so it stops on setted breakpoints?

Thanks for help

Comment: What do you mean when you say it starts in "debug mode"?

Comment: How did  you started `tomcat` in debug mode ?

Comment: I choose the project I want to debug and right klick than Debug As->Debug on Server->Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost. Than the server starts and shows the application surface as if I were running the project, without stopping at setted breakpoints. But in the server-view the tomcat is shown as running in "Debugging, Synchronized".